# Import csv and make mathematical operation with its cells in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to import csv and make mathematical operations with some specific cells for example: `(C111-C12)/(B111-B12)`, I tried to import csv like this:

```
A_data = dataset('xlsfile','exceldata_A.csv');
```

and then the operation I tried is:

`(A_data.C111-A_data.C12)/(A_data.B111-A_data.B12)` but I am getting a bunch of errors how can I specify the cells I want to use?

Comment: yes it is. You tried anything? Read the docs perhaps?

Comment: http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/312984 this is what I tried

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about dataset (maybe your problem is due to using 'xlsfile' for a CSV file ?), but if the file is in CSV format I would use [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) function:

```
A_data = csvread('exceldata_A.csv');
```

Then, instead of (A_data.C111-A_data.C12)/(A_data.B111-A_data.B12), you can access line 111 and column C (column number 3) with A_data(111,3) :

```
(A_data(111,3)-A_data(12,3))/(A_data(111,2)-A_data(12,2))
```